# How can implement SAML SSO 2.0 in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am new to develop `SAML SSO 2.0`, I don't have any idea, How i can implement `SSO` in my application. I need to implement `SAML2` with my application. 
**Explanation:** I have **application A**, Where use come and will type `username` and `password` after all validation successfully done, then user will redirect to **application B** by using `SMAL SSO 2.0`. I am not aware about `SAML XML` and `SAML code`. How should i start this implementation. And i don't want to use any third party `DLL` or `library` in my project. 
Thanks to all in advance. Any one have done this or can guide me to implement this `SAML SSO 2.0` with `Asp.Net C#`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use anything 3rd-party? Creating your own authentication scheme (even to be compliant with a known standard) is full of risk. You will just end up making all the mistakes and having all the security holes which are already fixed in someone else's product - and they are big teams containing experts in this field, where you are one person who is not expert. Also why not just make use of the features of ASP.NET Identity? That's built-in, no 3rd parties required even. If you have a shared identity provider between the two applications then you should be able to achieve SSO.

Comment: If you want to create this as a learning exercise to improve your knowledge about this kind of thing then great, but then you should be doing lots of research yourself instead of asking for a ready-made guide or implementation. If you're doing this for a real application then see my advice above (i.e. **if you value your application's security then don't do it, use a proven existing solution instead**).

Comment: I would read this if I were you (https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43)

Comment: Hi @ADyson, Actually, I need to customize this . that's why, i don't want use third party DLL

Comment: Customise how exactly? And why? You either implement the standard or you don't. I'm not a seasoned expert on SAML but I'm not sure how much room for manoeuvre you've got, depending what you're trying to achieve. You might still be better to use a standard product and then see if it is extensible / configurable to your requirements.

Comment: P.S. Since you're asking for an implementation guide, it would have been sensible to mention your exact customisation requirement details up-front, otherwise, even if anyone was going to provide you with guidance, they would have been unable to take that into account. If customisation is the key reason for wanting to do this, then surely it would be the first thing you say.

Comment: What IDP are you using? Why does it have to be SAML? What about OpenID Connect?

Comment: Hi @nzpcmad, i am using IDP and SP both SSO, But not aware about SAML XML file, how it can be created and how it works.

Comment: Yes - but which IDP? Your own? Azure AD? ...

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with: don't try to invent a new wheel. Authorization and Authentication is *hard* and not for the faint of heart. It's a world in it's own right and with a reason.

I would recommend reading (not just looking) at ComponentSpace SAML 2 object and IdentityServer4 and perhaps read some articles from Brock Allen (https://brockallen.com/) before you even *consider* rolling your own.

> And i don't want to use any third party DLL or library in my project.

You're in for a world of hurt...